# JAVA - No puedo imprimir completamente de mi XML

Tags: java, xml

estoy desarrollando un programa que me permita imprimir los elementos de etiquetas de un XML que tengo, esta es la instrucción que esta es mi clase main, que me permite imprimir de cierta etiqueta:

```
    for(int k=0; k < list3.getLength(); k++) {
                 Node node3 = list3.item(k);

                 if(node3.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                  Element element3 = (Element) node3;

                  Concepto concepto3 = new Concepto();

                      concepto3.setCodigo(element3.getElementsByTagName("Codigo").item(0).getTextContent());
                      concepto3.setDescripcion(element3.getElementsByTagName("Descripcion").item(0).getTextContent());
                      concepto3.setUT(element3.getElementsByTagName("UT").item(0).getTextContent());
                      concepto3.setMonto(element3.getElementsByTagName("Monto").item(0).getTextContent()); 

                      ListaConceptos.add(concepto3);
                      System.out.println(concepto3);

System.out.println(concepto.toString2());

            }
        }
```

Y este es un pedazo de las etiquetas que necesito imprimir:

```
<OperacionesManoObra>
<OperacionManoObra>
<UT>0</UT>
<Monto>0</Monto>
</OperacionManoObra>
<OperacionManoObra>
<UT>0</UT>
<Monto>0</Monto>
</OperacionManoObra>
<OperacionManoObra>
<Codigo>SN</Codigo>
<Descripcion>VEHIC.EN BANCADA:COLOCAR-QUITAR</Descripcion>
<UT>15</UT>
<Monto>337.5</Monto>
</OperacionManoObra>
<OperacionManoObra>
<Codigo>SN</Codigo>
<Descripcion>BANCADA:PREPARAR</Descripcion>
<UT>10</UT>
<Monto>225</Monto>
</OperacionesManoObra>
```

Donde yo veo que radica el problema, es que los primeros dos elementos, solo tienen las etiquetas "UT" y "Monto", y las demás ya continuan normal... cómo podría arreglarlo para que en los primeros dos me imprima nulo los que no tiene?, gracias.

Comment: Te está dando un NullPointerException?

Comment: @PabloLozano es correcto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no compruebas si hay un valor o no, con lo que intentas acceder a algo que no existe. Debes comprobarlo antes:

```
for(int k=0; k < list3.getLength(); k++) {
    Node node3 = list3.item(k);

    if(node3.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element element3 = (Element) node3;

        Concepto concepto3 = new Concepto();

        //Devuelve null si no existe
        Element elem = element3.getElementsByTagName("Codigo").item(0);
        if (elem != null) { 
            concepto3.setCodigo(elem.getTextContent());
        }
        elem = element3.getElementsByTagName("Descripcion").item(0);
        if (elem != null) { 
            concepto3.setDescripcion(elem.getTextContent());
        }
        elem = element3.getElementsByTagName("UT").item(0);
        if (elem != null) { 
            concepto3.setUT(elem.getTextContent());
        }                      
        elem = element3.getElementsByTagName("Monto").item(0);
        if (elem != null) { 
            concepto3.setMonto(elem.getTextContent());
        }               

        ListaConceptos.add(concepto3);
        System.out.println(concepto3);

   }
}
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco totalmente!!!